# I Try to make a discord bot and I got this error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I make a discord bot and got this error

I try to add when a member send hello the bot reply hi
I do it form a tutorial in youtube for a server.

and i got this error:

> C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1132
> error: new Error("Used disallowed intents")
> ^
>
> Error: Used disallowed intents
> at WebSocketShard.onClose (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1132:18)
> at connection.onclose (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:676:17)
> at callListener (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
> at WebSocket.onClose
> (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:220:9)
> at WebSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at WebSocket.emitClose (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:258:10)
> at TLSSocket.socketOnClose (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\akikloforita\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1264:15)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
> at node:net:323:12
> at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7)
>
> Node.js v18.17.0

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
],
});

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log(`✅ ${c.user.tag} is online.`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('Hey!');
    }
})

client.login("my_token")

Can someone help me?
```

Answer (score 4):

Enable `Guild Members` and `Message Content` Privileged Intents in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `Server Members` intent and `Message Content` intent on your Application [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications)